# How can I achieve this with bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello StackOverflow I have the following code, this works with bootstrap and Pixedelic camera:

```
<section id="slider" class="container-fluid">
<div class="row fluid">
    <div id="camera_wrap_1">
        <div data-src="content/images/slider1.png"></div>
        <div data-src="content/images/slider1.png"></div>
        <div data-src="content/images/slider1.png"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The camera runs fine is the blue image, but I want to achive this boxes over the camera wrap. Like this

[Image](http://es.tinypic.com/r/id7qc8/8)

The white boxes needs to be aligned respect 4 columns bootstrap col-md-3 but be over the content of the camera. The blue is slider1.png is part of the content of camera plugin than is a full width image.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a example o a bootstrap carousel.

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/carousel.js"></script>


<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-bGl8UEECI8A/UH1o5UwxvdI/AAAAAAAABEg/L0iomiHX330/s640/old+bridge.jpg" alt="Ye olde bridge">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          The old bridge
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://bashooka.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/fantasy-landscape-15.jpg" alt="Elves land">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          Elves landscape
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

  <!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Hello David Lemon this is not what I want achieve, because is inside the item so when some one clicks over the control left or right the Carousel Caption will vary. I need a static boxes over the pixdelic camera.